# Clausura en funciones de js

Tags: javascript-objeto

Al insertar una función en la consola del navegador se genera un error y no alcanzo a percatarme del cual es el error. La situación es la siguiente

```
const sayHello = function(){
 
let greetingMsg = "Greetings ";
 
function msgTo(firstName, lastName){
 
greetingMsg = greetingMsg + firstName + " " + lastName;
 
}
 
return {
 
sendGreeting: function(firstName, lastName){
 
msgTo(firstName, lastName);
 
}
 
getMsg: function(){
 
return greetingMsg;
 
}
 
}
 
}
const createMsg = sayHello();
createMsg.sendGreeting(("Professor" , "Falken");
console.log(creatMsg.getMsg());
```

Quisiera conocer dónde está el error para comprender la función con mayor claridad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré al menos dos errores que hay que arreglar.

Primero, que al crear la constante `const createMsg`, luego la llamas con otro nombre en el `console.log(creatMsg.getMsg());`.

Ten en cuenta usar bien los nombres de las variables. Te recomendaría que los copies y pegues al reutilizarlos para evitar ese tipo de errores.

Después, otra cosa que te faltó es agregar una coma entre la propiedad `sendGreeting` y `getMsg`.

Al declarar un objeto en JavaScript siempre hay que separar sus propiedades por comas.

Haciendo esas correcciones, el código quedaría así:

```js
const sayHello = function(){
 
  let greetingMsg = "Greetings ";
 
  function msgTo(firstName, lastName){
 
    greetingMsg = greetingMsg + firstName + " " + lastName;

  }
 
  return {
 
    sendGreeting: function(firstName, lastName){
 
      msgTo(firstName, lastName);
 
    },
 
    getMsg: function(){
      
      return greetingMsg;
 
    }
 
  }
 
}

const createMsg = sayHello();
createMsg.sendGreeting("Professor" , "Falken");
console.log(createMsg.getMsg());
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Aclaré donde se encontraba el error